Answering Questions with common answers, that are against Site Rules
So, preface - in the Corporate world - there are often scenarios that are pretty common, enough that we could give a common answer to... Even though we do not know specifically the exact reason why and ordinarily would VTC such a question due to it being specific to workplace policy etc.
Case in point - there was a recent question I marked VTC, as it was about a lengthy interview process, where the interviewee was promised a position, did additional interviews - then was told thanks but no thanks.
As it stands - the only person that can actually answer the question as to why this was - is the Company or HR person.
But... In this type of scenario there is usually 3-4 scenarios that could explain it. As Such, we could answer along those lines:
It is likely 1,2,3 or 4.
And so I am torn - because part of me thinks that writing a meta-answer about common Corporate happenings not only helps the asker of the question (thus leading to overall increase in site satisfaction) but also helps other people in similar situations.
However, on the flipside these answers would be mere speculation and against the Ethos of SE.
Thoughts

My two cents: (1) speculation and guessing just for the sake of an answer is not good (2) the reason for vtc-ing instead of answering is because, just as you said, you help the user posting the question... but, most likely, you "help" them and only them, not any other user that may browse seeking help (3) sometimes even on those posts (company-specific) we can "read between the lines" and work an answer (kinda like mhoran says in their answer) and (4) seldomly done here as things are not that black or white, but we could work and write a Canonical Q&A that covers these cases

@DarkCygnus - I hear that, I am on the fence - My experience of the Corporate world is that there are an awful lot of similarities. And for someone new to that world, outlining what those commonalities are I think has some value. I will see what others think

@TheDemonLord who is this site for, if not "someone new to [the corporate] world"? Or whatever working world they are inexperienced in?

I don't see any harm in answering such a question with (justified) speculation. People are human. They are going to wonder. Such events are going to impact their mental state no matter how much people tell them to move on. Being about to understand potential justifications for the scenario does indeed help.

@PlayerOne - That is a good point

@GregoryCurrie - I guess that is at the heart of my quandry - Justified Speculation vs Unjustified speculation. Where that delves into the realm of VTC for being about something company specific or opinion based vs reasonable options.

The example situation that you discuss

where the interviewee was promised a position, did additional
interviews - then was told thanks but no thanks.

can best be answered with the following:
It doesn't matter why. Communication during the hiring process is designed to keep quality candidates around by telling them it is looking good. Which means you can't trust their statements.
When they do tell you that they aren't hiring you, the reason doesn't matter: you lost this unique competition, with unique requirements, against a unique set of candidates. Next time you might win, or even do worse.
The only time it makes a difference is if you fail quickly, then you want to know why so you don't keep failing the same way.
That is an answer that doesn't have to give reason.
On the money website they get questions where people want to know detailed descriptions related to a specific potential scam. They want to know so they try and scam the scammer. The best answers are light on details: just point out a few red flags and then end the answer.

Completely agree - this is a useful answer that will help anyone in a similar situation. There's nothing "company specific" going on here at all.
